# Is there any visual tool available to read a file with extension of ".xsl" (eXtended Stylesheet Language) file and show data in tabular format?

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have a file with extension of .xsl, which has around 4000 lines and contains around 100 tables in it. My work is to align each table in proper format.
Is there any simplest way to align all tables?
Is there any visual tool which shows table data in grid view?
Code is pasted below

```
<xslt code><table><tr><td></td></tr><table></xslt code>
```

Comment: Are you asking about the xslt itself, or of the output produced?

Comment: @Carlos: I want to change **xslt itself** . so I can see output with proper alignment.

Comment: then you can use any program that can format xml, as an xsl is an xml.

Comment: @Carlos: can you please suggest any good free visual tool which is used to align this table tags?

Comment: hi Prasad, have you tried with Eclipse, Intellilj, Notepad++ ? Most IDEs have an option to format, and many text editors too.